# Generation of all days in a month in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am designing a report where I need to display all days in a month(ex: 1- 30 for month of april) and display information associated to it. But my report displays only dates that have data associated to it and ignores all other days. Is there any way to display all the days in the report irrespective of the data?

Comment: What does the query look like that is getting the data? You need to fill in the empty days in that query I would assume.

Comment: I am getting the data from a WCF service which gets the data from a stored procedure. How do I fill in the empty days in the query?

Answer (score 2):

As Wil hints at in his comment, it is easiest to generate these days in your dataset/query. This is a perfect place to use a CTE (Common Table Expression). These generate a table that you can use in your query, and they support recursion, so it is easy to generate a table with as many days as you want.

A Google of "cte days in a month" gave me this link as one of the top results: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/

Please leave a comment if this doesn't make sense.

OK, here's a sample using a CTE with days of the current month.

```
WITH  DaysOfMonthCTE
        AS ( SELECT  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartDate ,
                     DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 1) AS EndDate
             UNION ALL
             SELECT  DATEADD(day, 1, StartDate) ,
                     DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate)
             FROM    DaysOfMonthCTE
             WHERE   EndDate < DATEADD(month,
                                       DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
           )
   SELECT   Student.Name ,
            DaysOfMonthCTE.StartDate ,
            AVG(Scores.TestScore) AS AverageScore
   FROM     myStudentsTable AS student
   INNER JOIN myScoresTable scores
            ON student.ID = scores.StudentID
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN DaysOfMonthCTE
            ON scores.TestDate >= DaysOfMonthCTE.StartDate
               AND scores.TestDate < DaysOfMonthCTE.EndDate
   GROUP BY Student.NAME ,
            DaysOfMonthCTE.StartDate
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I can generate days in dataset but I have data that is associated with it. i.e the report should have  all the days (1 to 30) in a row and and under each date column the data needs to be displayed. I tried to cross apply the new table with my stored procedure but that results in tons of data and is killing my WCF service..

Comment: You don't need to cross apply the new table...just left join the results of the query to the results of the CTE.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check back earlier, but Wil is spot on: Say you create a CTE called DaysOfMonth, then use a

     SELECT DaysOfMonth.DayStart, blah
     FROM DaysOfMonth LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable on myTable.DateColumn >= DaysOfMonth.DayStart and myTable.DateColumn < DaysOfMonth.DayEnd

Comment: If you edit your question, you can post your current version of the query. What was the name of the CTE you used? (The format is "With MyCTEName AS (<TableDefinition>) SELECT * from MyCTEName ...")

Comment: Do I need to put my stored procedure's result set in a temp table and then apply the CTE?

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @JamieF is spot-on but I was looking for a more general purpose date generator where I can get a list of dates between a start date and end date.  The OP asked for all the days in a month, so this answer is not really for the OP.  I added here in the event someone (like me) is looking for how to generate sequential data in a range on the fly in SSRS.

I merely added the following as the basis for my query in a dataset, and used two parameters - @StartDate and @EndDate.

```
;with  DateGenerator
as (
select
    CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate) GeneratedDate 
union all select
    DATEADD(day, 1, GeneratedDate)
from
    DateGenerator
where GeneratedDate < @EndDate
)
select
    GeneratedDate
from
    DateGenerator

option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

**Beware** - limit is range of 32767 days.  If the range is larger than that this solution will implode.

To use, merely join your query to the pseudotable DateGenerator (line above 'option' statement)